# Random complex eigenvalues and averages of traces

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, random-matrices

Suppose I have a random matrix $M$ which is real, but not symmetric. Suppose I know that the marginal distribution of its eigenvalues is uniform over the unit disk in the complex plane. What does that tell me about the average values of traces, $\langle {\rm Tr}(M^n)\rangle$, $\langle {\rm Tr}(M^n){\rm Tr}(M^m)\rangle$, etc?

Comment: Since the characteristic polynomial is real, the complex eigenvalues have to come in pairs; thus they can't be individually independently uniformly distributed. You'll have to say more about what you mean by this uniform distribution.

Comment: @joriki What I mean is that if you plot all the eigenvalues from many realizations of the random matrix, you will see a uniform cloud of points inside the unit disk. They will be correlated, of course, but any one eigenvalue will have uniform probaility density of taking any value inside the disk

Answer (score 1):

$$\newcommand{\Tr}{\mathrm{Tr}}$$
Here's a hint:  Enumerate the eigenvalues of $M$ as $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ (note that these are random).  Then $$\Tr(M^n) = \lambda_1^n + \cdots + \lambda_k^n\,.$$  Expand this and take expectations.

Comment: $\Tr(M)^n = (\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k)^n$, whereas $\Tr(M^n) = \lambda_1^n + \cdots + \lambda_k^n$.

Comment: Oh yes, that's exactly what I meant!  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: In order to take the expectation of a product of eigenvalues, I would need to know their correlations. I don't know that. I only know their overall density.

Comment: @thedude, without knowing more information you cannot find mixed moments, but this expectation is always zero.  Do you have any other information?

Comment: @MarcusM I don't expect to be able to compute very much, I just want to know what it is that I can compute.

Comment: For instance, if $z$ is uniformly distributed in the unit disk, then $\langle |z|^{2n}\rangle=\frac{2}{n+2}$. Does something similar to this appear in the matrix moments?